# Proceeding to another activity by clicking TextView

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to click the textView so it can go to the second class activity

```
public void click(View v){
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.titleExpense:
                intent = new Intent(this,userExpense.class);
                break;
            case R.id.titleIncome:
                intent = new Intent(this,userIncome.class);
                break;

        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The error I have is the intent startActivity(intent), I'm not entirely sure where I'm suppose to declare it.

Layout: (Same for the Income one)

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titleExpense"
        android:id="@+id/titleExpense"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

From the manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".userExpense" />
        <activity android:name=".userIncome"></activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: can you post full code!

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: please check my answer @Ralph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Your method needs to be named `onClick`, not `click`.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.titleExpense:
            intent = new Intent(this,userExpense.class);
            break;
        case R.id.titleIncome:
            intent = new Intent(this,userIncome.class);
            break;

    }
    if (null!=intent) startActivity(intent);
  }
```

---

Or, use the Java code to setOnClickListener into the textview.

Comment: Also put the startActivity() inside the case definition to avoid compile time error or have a default case to initialize the intent.

Comment: Agree with this, but if it does not work, upload error messages too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
public void click(View v){
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.titleExpense:
                intent = new Intent(this,userExpense.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.titleIncome:
                intent = new Intent(this,userIncome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }   
    }
```

Comment: No more error, but now I have another problem. Even when set as clickable true it's still not working

Comment: Did you added the userExpense and userIncome classes in android manifest.xml file @Ralph

Comment: @Daryl The activities are in there

Comment: remove  android:onClick="onClick"  or  edit android:onClick="click"

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to '`this`' , it refers to instance of `View` you clicked, you can use `getApplicationContext()`  to refer to parent Activity and always use default with switch case to avoid null errors ,try below code

```
        public void click(View v){
                    Intent intent;
                    switch(v.getId()){
                        case R.id.titleExpense:
                            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userExpense.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.titleIncome:
                        default :
                            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),userIncome.class);
                            break;

                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your xml

For example,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width=blahblah
    android:layout_height=blahblah
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

and in java file,

```
tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.titleExpense:
            intent = new Intent(this,userExpense.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.titleIncome:
            intent = new Intent(this,userIncome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'titleExpense'

Comment: @Ralph You don't need the XML onClick when you have `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public void click(View v){
    Intent intent;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.titleExpense:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userExpense.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.titleIncome:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userIncome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the onclickListener and intialized for the views in oncreate

Sample

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

        Button titleExpense= (Button) findViewById(R.id.titleExpense);
        titleExpense.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button titleIncome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titleIncome);
        titleIncome.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.titleExpense:
                intent = new Intent(this,userExpense.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.titleIncome:
                intent = new Intent(this,userIncome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Do i really need the button, because its a text view not a button

Comment: whatever your view is you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Try This i.e make Intent Global;

```
 Intent intent;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.text:
            intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```